# How might I use a batch file to read the contents of one file and save it into another file?

Tags: batch-file

I have created a file, file1.txt, the content of this file is like "abcdef".
I want to read the content of this file and wish to store content in another file "output.txt" using a batch file.

Please let me know how to do it from batch file.

Comment: You don't explicitly mention if you want to process the contents of "file1.txt" - otherwise you can copy the file using the `copy` command. I suspect that this is not what you want. Therefore I would urge you to carefully reword your question to make it clear and state what you've tried so far. Also, using all capitals makes your question less legible and is widely considered bad netiquette since it is akin to you shouting.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  And please, when you reply use mixed case.  Posts in ALL UPPER CASE are hard to read (and considered rude).

Answer (score 3):

Your batch file could simply copy the file to the new filename.

```
copy c:\file1.txt c:\output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want to copy the file, in which case you can use the following:

```
COPY "C:\FILE1.TXT" "C:\OUTPUT.TXT"
```

If that's not what you had in mind, I suggest you clarify the question or dig through the excellent reference [here](http://ss64.com/nt/).

Answer (score 0):

Ruchi, your question sounds like you simply want to copy the contents of the file from 'FILE1.TXT' to 'OUTPUT.TXT', is that right?  You do not want to change the file in any way?  If so, there are lots of ways to do this:

```
@ECHO OFF
COPY C:\FILE1.TXT C:\OUTPUT.TXT
```

or

```
@ECHO OFF
TYPE C:\FILE1.TXT > C:\OUTPUT.TXT
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to overwrite the existing file:

```
type file1.txt > output.txt
```

You can do this to append to the existing file:

```
type file1.txt >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
rem  -- output file1 to file2 --
type %1 > %2
```

To use it, say the batch file is named output.bat, use command:

```
output.bat input.txt output.txt
```